# VBox.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS) not working

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there any way to set full height of element ?
I have tried `VBox.setVgrow(node , Priority.ALWAYS);` but it is not working .

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"    minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="258.0" prefWidth="197.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
      <TextField prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="193.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ddd;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

[image: Scene Builder Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In FXML add `maxHeight="+Infinity"` to TextField.

In code `txtfld.setMaxHeight( Double.MAX_VALUE );`

Comment: Thanks , but how to add it through api  ``public final void setMaxHeight(double value)``?